# Practice Welsh Pronunciation in Duolingo

Tags: duolingo

I've been using Duolingo to learn Welsh recently. My wife, seeing my progress, has installed the app to learn Portuguese. It's only now (having seen my wife practicing) that I realise there is a "pronunciation mode" which uses the phone microphone to capture and score you pronunciation. This mode hasn't presented itself to me at all.

Is it not available on the Welsh course? Or do I need to activate it somehow in the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only some languages have that feature, and unfortunately Welsh does not.